# How to serve image raw binary data in nodejs

Tags: node.js, buffer, readfile, binary-data, nodejs-stream

I have an img tag in my html that requests the image from nodejs server. In my server js file I have below code to send image response but I observed data is not rendered on client side. Any suggestions?

```
const getFile = (filePath) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(filePath, (error, data) => {
            if (!error) {
                resolve(data);
            } // enter code here
            else reject(error);
        });
    });
};

getFile(test.jpg).then((data) => {
    response.statusCode = "200";
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpg");
    response.end(data, "base64"); // Also tried response.end(data, "binary")
})
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this an Express application? If so, your best bet is to use the [static middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). Put all your static (binary) files in one folder, expose it with the static middleware, and load it that way.

Comment: This is plain nodejs application. Not using express.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fs.readFile, using fs.createReadStream and piping the chunks worked for images.

```
let frstream = fs.createReadStream(url);
        response.statusCode = "200";
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
        frstream.pipe(response);
```